# How to find out if my page is being used?

Tags: javascript

is there any way how to find out if my page is being used now? I mean, if is it on the user screen. tab with page is active on the screen. I have some server-client data flow and i want to optimize it. I want to have data flowing just if user is watching page, not when page is open in browser but hidden in non-active tab. 
Does anybody know? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see if the tab is currently visible (not a hidden tab), then you can use [the visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API).

[Here's](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/static/vis.js) an example of a small function letting you on most browsers both register for visibility change events and check the visibility :

```
//  var visible = vis(); // gives the current state
//  vis(function(){ ... });   // register a visibility change event handler
var vis = (function(){
        var stateKey, eventKey, keys = {
                hidden: "visibilitychange",
                webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
                mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
                msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
        };
        for (stateKey in keys) {
                if (stateKey in document) {
                        eventKey = keys[stateKey];
                        break;
                }
        }
        return function(c) {
                if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
                return !document[stateKey];
        }
})();
```

[Demonstration](http://dystroy.org/demos/vis.html)